# Android app goes completely white after first launch and splash screen is shown

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile, apk

I have built a flutter application which works perfectly fine when debugging but as soon as I build an apk and try to install it on a device, the splash screen runs and then the screen goes completely white. Note: not greyish like how the debug error screen show up on release mode.

```
e: /Users/priscilla/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c4988ff80110f75080a936fc6f044848/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/priscilla/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/priscilla/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/priscilla/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/priscilla/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/priscilla/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I get this when I build a signed release apk but the build is successful.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await setUpLocator();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(const MobileScaffoldApp(isDebug: false));
}
```

I'm assuming the problem might be one of these as everything else runs fine within the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white screen was caused by a routing issue on the main method's run app. All I did was run the app in profile mode and got to the root of the problem. It seemed to only occur in release mode so profile provided me all the resource to fix it.

It was completely independent of the Kotlin version discrepancy (which ended up not affecting much).

Answer (score 0):

May be u would be using packages which needs proguard-rules.pro file check that if that works

Comment: I created a proguard-rule.pro file and added set minifyEnabled and useProguard to true in the app-level build.gradle file. But I got errors about 

Could not find method useProguard() for arguments [true] on BuildType$AgpDecorated_Decorated